# Having problems with Norwegian Data Encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I encoded Norwegian data using `data.encode('ISO-8859-1','ignore')` while writing the data into a .csv file. But i do not get the string in the correct format. I tried all other possible encodings. I read somewhere that this is a problem with python 2.7 . Is it true?
Hope someone can help.
For example :

for å i get Ã¥
for ø i get Ã¸ and so on...

I noticed that when i extract it to a .txt file, it shows correct format. Can it be a Microsoft office issue? I am using MS Office 2010

Comment: "do not get the string in the correct format" could mean just about anything. You may need to describe your problem in a bit more detail.

Comment: you have data in UTF-8, and you're parsing it as ISO-8859-1

Comment: i used UTF-8 as well. While printing, it displays correct format. But when i write on a .csv file then i can see the incorrect formatting